# Externally linked javascript files and the file protocol?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so I have what I believe to be a bizzare issue. When I run my site that I'm coding through a server such as MAMP, the site correctly loads all of the externally linked Javascript files.

However, when I load the site off of my laptop, no server running (ie - file://path/to/html.html), the browser (Chrome and Safari, in this case) do not load the external js files.

How I'm linking the external files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.slides.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/language.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slideController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/general.js"></script>
```

In the head tags.

Comment: you are using `/` before your path. `/` Takes you to the `root` folder, check this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the URLs start with a `/`, that will go straight to the root of the filesystem (or, IIRC, the root of the current letter drive on Windows).

URL resolution and security differences usually means that it just isn't worth doing development work without running a web server for testing.